# Java construct one instance of Certain Class from another instance

Tags: java

I am a java beginner. My test code like this:

```
public class Test {
    private String a;
    private String b;

    public Test(String a, String b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public Test(Test another){
        this.a = another.a;//My question comes from here
        this.b = another.b;
    }
    public String getA(){
        return a;
    }

    public String getB(){
        return b;
    }
}
```

My question is why `Test another` can access the `private variable` directly using `.`, rather than using the `getA()` or `getB()` method.

The tutorial tells me that `private variable` can not be accessed directly by `.`

Comment: Thank you. I got the answer from your link.

Answer (score 0):

Private variables cannot be accessed by a different class, but here you are in the same class.